# Does the index in Firestore count?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I've read that for every query an index is automatically created. So if I create this query:

```
db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("admin", true);
```

And I get one result, is an index created for **admin** property? If yes, does this take space from the document quota?

Comment: It's worth noting that indexes are not free. All indexes **do occupy space**, and this counts toward the overall size of the database, for the purpose of billing, even if it doesn't affect the total size of each individual document.

Comment: Thank you very much @DougStevenson for this information. Is exactly what I was looking for, to be sure it doesn't count from each document quota.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query does not take space for the document. The space of the document is in the document itself below your users collection; each document will have its own size, and this size will not be affected with the index for each field

The index is created for the documents your query matches, but you are only billed for the documents you access with that condition only.

From [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#single-field-indexes):

> An index behind every query If no index exists for a query, most
> databases crawl through their contents item by item, a slow process
> that slows down even more as the database grows. Cloud Firestore
> guarantees high query performance by using indexes for all queries. As
> a result, query performance depends on the size of the result set and
> not on the number of items in the database.
>
> Less index management, more app development Cloud Firestore includes
> features that reduce the amount of time you need to spend managing
> indexes. The indexes required for the most basic queries are
> automatically created for you. As you use and test your app, Cloud
> Firestore helps you identify and create additional indexes your app
> requires.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. My question is not about the query is about the index that is created for the `admin` field that exist in user document. So if it is an index created does it take space from 1Mb?

Comment: you can have up to 40.000 indexed fields in each document, the space is just for the document , not for the indexes

Comment: My question is not about the number of indexes is about the index that is created for a field. And if it is created, does it count from that document space, this is the question.

Comment: I answered that, the index is not count as the document size, just the document elements itself

Comment: The index itself has also limits, you can check https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas

Comment: But those index quotas are not related in any way to the document itself, right?

Comment: As I have already told, the index does not count for the document size

Comment: It's worth noting that indexes are not free. All indexes **do occupy space**, and this counts toward the overall size of the database, for the purpose of billing, even if it doesn't affect the total size of each individual document.